# Delete user account Dialog - firebase with React JS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

This dialog must delete the user authentication info of the currently signed user:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import fire, { firestore } from '../config';

var user = fire.auth().currentUser;
var email = user ? user.email.toString() : "";
var password = "";
var typedPassword = "";

class DeleteConfirmationDialog extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        user = fire.auth().currentUser;
        email = fire.auth().currentUser.email;
        console.log(email)
        firestore.collection("User").where("email", "==", email)
            .get()
            .then((querySnapshot) => {
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    password = doc.data().password;
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
            });
    }

    del = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (password === typedPassword) {
            firestore.collection("User").where('email', '==', email).get().then((snap) => {
                snap.forEach((doc) => {
                    doc.ref.delete();
                    console.log("DOC FUNCTION")
                })
            }).then(function () {
                user.delete();
                console.log("SUCCESS")
            })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                })
        } else {
            console.log("Password is NOT correct")
        }
    }

    handleInputChange = (e) => {
        typedPassword = e.target.value;
        console.log(password)
        console.log(typedPassword)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <center className='delete-Dialog' >
                <p style={{ margin: '3px' }}>For your security, please re-enter your password to continue</p>
                <form>
                    <input type='password' placeholder='Password' className='inputForDelete' onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                    <br />
                    <button className='continue' onClick={this.del}>continue</button>
                </form>
            </center>
        );
    }
}
export default DeleteConfirmationDialog;
```

It should delete the authentication data and delete the User from firestore collection at the same time. When I click to submit, it says "SUCCESS" but I still see that user in the firebase and can login again, what may be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `e.preventDefault()` at the beginning of the function `del` like:

```
const del = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // rest of your code
 }
```

It will not reload the page after clicking on the button. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Did you check if it is been deleted in firebase database after click? Even if the page loads again?